# IllegalStateException while casting context

Tags: java, android

I am trying to cast an activity to a FragmentActivty object so I could get FragmentManager object

```
public class Main extends ListActivity {
...
   public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
        FragmentActivity myContext=(FragmentActivity) getApplicationContext(); //Here: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

        FragmentManager fragManager = myContext.getFragmentManager();
        DialogFragment newFragment = new uSharedUtility.TimePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(fragManager, "timePicker");
    }
}
```

But when doing it I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
```

I cant use `getFragmentManager` directly because my activity extends from `ListActivity` which is very necessary.

Please suggest me to get around this error, i really need to use both ListAdapter & Date/Time pickers in the same activity.

Comment: `IllegalStateException` doesn't occur due to casting; it's thrown when you attempt to call a method and states that method depends on are not set to what they should be. If anything, you'd get a `ClassCastException`

Comment: @VinceEmigh The root cause exception is wrapped in the `IllegalStateException` wheb e.g. an `onClick` handler throws.

Comment: @laato My bad, didn't think of that. This is why a full stacktrace is always good to have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cant use `getFragmentManager` directly because my activity extends from `ListActivity` which is very necessary.

It isn't necessary. You can have a `ListView` in any activity.

Since you're already using fragments, consider using a `ListFragment` with a `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: list methods like `setListAdapter` & `onListItemClick` becomes unabialble when i extend it from `FragmentActivity` instead of `ListActivity `

Comment: You can call similar methods directly on the ListView. Or ListFragment.

Comment: if if expend from `FragmentActivity ` i get error over this ` super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);` how can i use this method then?

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast Application Context to Activity, you must need Activity Context.

```
(FragmentActivity) getApplicationContext() // Not Possible
```

getContext(): Returns the context the view is currently running in. Usually the currently active Activity.

getApplicationContext(): Returns the context for the entire application (the process all the Activities are running inside of). Use this instead of the current Activity context if you need a context tied to the lifecycle of the entire application, not just the current Activity.

Comment: `getContext():` i cant find this method anywhere? can you link me to the online docs for this?

Comment: Can you please share your complete class in which you have to use this. Also try with v.getContext().

Comment: i have updated my question with the class definition please check and `v.getContext()` also gives same error

Comment: @Maven You cant cast ListActivity to FragmentActivity. In your case v.getContext() will return ListActivity. :( You must have to use/extend with FragmentActivity.