# Using List Adapter in a Fragment Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an activity class that extends from `FragmentActivity` as I am using `DialogFragment` in it.

Earlier this class was extended from `ListActivity` and there was no issues [but when I extended it from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27679008/illegalstateexception-while-casting-context/27679029) `FragmentActivity` when the requirement of `DialogFragment` arrive the method `setListAdapter` becomes unavaible.

I want to know that how can I use the method `setListAdapter` while extending my class from `FragmentActivity`

```
public class Main extends FragmentActivity{
            …
            …
    private class fetchStudentInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<mStudentInfo>> {
        @Override
        protected List<mStudentInfo> doInBackground(String... urls) {
            …
        }

        public void onPostExecute(List<mStudentInfo> StudentInfoCollection) {
            setListAdapter(new StudentInfoAdapter((Activity) mainAppContext, StudentInfoCollection));
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Use this method on the reference of the list view.

Comment: I didn't get you, what do you mean by `on the reference of the list view`. Can you please explain it a bit?

Comment: Now when you changed it to a FragmentActivity, you must be having a list view where you want to load your data. Set your adapter to that list view using setAdapter() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For setting setAdapter you need a listView reference like this ,

```
public class Main extends FragmentActivity {

  private ListView mListView; 
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_id);
    mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
 }

 private class fetchStudentInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<mStudentInfo>> {
        @Override
        protected List<mStudentInfo> doInBackground(String... urls) {
            …
        }

        public void onPostExecute(List<mStudentInfo> StudentInfoCollection) {
            mListView.setListAdapter(new StudentInfoAdapter((Activity) mainAppContext, StudentInfoCollection));
        }
    }

}
```

And also you need layout file with a listview inside with id **R.id.list**.